# Retrieve values from given array with same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, which I can either do the simple approach, which is do a For Each loop on each array, and if one way is the method, accept it, or vice-versa, or is it possible to set values in an array with the same key value?

Like:

```
<?php
$Array = Array('UniqueValue' => 'Key',
               'UniqueValue_2' => 'Key',
               'DifferentValue' => 'Key_2'); // and etc...
?>
```

I could probably try trial and error, but another method would be somehow integrating the arrays and only reading the values I need?

Thanks for your guys' time.

ah, quick edit. I feel like someone's going to bring this up, so I read [Nested array, get items with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350288/nested-array-get-items-with-same-key) and I tried, but it's not working for me. It reads only the first value, and I'm not breaking the loop. If you want to see the code I'm working with, I'll gladly add it.

Actually, I found a better way to word this, so!

I need to iterate through each array value with the same key in a For Each loop.

Like so:

```
ForEach($Array as $Key){ // or $Key => $Value
    If($Key == 'Key'){
        Echo $Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. You want to merge arrays whilst preserving duplicate keys?

Comment: No, that's just a possibility. What I want to do is use the duplicate keys for each value. So if I were to pull every value I wanted, I could just set the key to the values I want, and call the key which pulls the values

Comment: Updated it, that should probably explain it a lot better :P

Comment: The usual notation is `key => value`, not the other way around. Maybe that's causing some confusion here.

Comment: Yeah, I reversed it maybe to see if that could be a possibility, but apparently not, as so far it's only going to the last value with the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$Array = Array(
    0 => Array('Test', 'Testing', 'Tester'),
    1 => Array('Test2'));

Print_R($Array[0]); // Array ( [0] => Test [1] => Testing [2] => Tester )
?>
```

Ah, I forgot about nesting arrays. Sorry about that, haha, but for anyone who would possibly need an answer, here you go.